# Edit PDF with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5

I have this form where the user provide us the information, something like this:

[image]

the data goes into a table in my database. After that I want to export the data to a pdf file which I already have:

[image]

the PDF file is already editable, so is there any way I can put the data into those editable fields?

Comment: Nothing to do with Laravel - you will need to look at PDF editing packages. FPDF is one